Salabim 3D animation example program is not running
I am running the example program, see below, from the 3D animation page of the salabim website (salabim is a discrete event simulation package in Python)
import salabim as sim

env = sim.Environment()
env.background_color("90%gray")
env.width(900)
env.height(700)
env.position((1000, 0))

env.width3d(900)
env.height3d(700)
env.position3d((0, 100))

env.animate(True)
env.animate(True)
env.animate3d(True)

env.show_camera_position()
env.show_camera_position(over3d=True)

sim.Animate3dGrid(x_range=range(-2, 3), y_range=range(-2, 3))
traj0 = sim.TrajectoryCircle(radius=2, vmax=1)
d0 = traj0.duration()
sim.Animate3dBox(x_len=1, y_len=1, z_len=1, color="red", x=lambda t: traj0.x(t % d0), y=lambda t: traj0.y(t % d0),
                 z=0.5, z_angle=lambda t: traj0.angle(t % d0))

traj1 = sim.TrajectoryCircle(radius=1, vmax=1, angle0=360, angle1=0)
d1 = traj1.duration()
sim.Animate3dBox(x_len=0.5, y_len=0.5, z_len=0.5, color="green", x=lambda t: traj1.x(t % d1),
                 y=lambda t: traj1.y(t % d1), z=0.25, z_angle=lambda t: traj1.angle(t % d1))

env.run(sim.inf)


I get the following error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rtap\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\rtap\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\rtap\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\salabim\salabim.py", line 12881, 
in simulate_and_animate_loop
     self.animation3d_init()
  File "C:\Users\rtap\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\salabim\salabim.py", line 10298, in animation3d_init
    glut.glutInit()
  File "C:\Users\rtap\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 333, in glutInit
    _base_glutInit( ctypes.byref(count), holder )
  File "C:\Users\rtap\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 423, in __call__
    raise error.NullFunctionError(
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rtap\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\salabim\salabim.py", line 12849, in run
    raise SimulationStopped
salabim.salabim.SimulationStopped

I created the python environment as follows:
conda create -n test_env python=3.9
conda activate -n test_env
conda install pip
pip install pillow
pip install pyopengl
pip install pyopengl_accelerate
pip install pywavefront
pip install pyglet==1.5.27
pip install opencv-python
pip install salabim
pip install greenlet

The error occurs at env.run(sim.inf). What am I doing wrong? Is my python environment not correct?

I solved it by doing what is in the manual:
If, after that you get a runtime error that glutInit is not defined, try to install from the Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages site at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl or (for more recent versions): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mz7faVsrp0e6IKCQh8MyZh-BcCqEGPwx?usp=sharing .
Then, find the right 3.1.5 or later version for you (e.g. for Python 3.7, 64 bits you use PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) and download that. Then issue
pip install wheelfile

,like (for the above package)
pip install PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

and it should work.
It is recommended to install pyopengl_accelerate in the same way, like
pip install PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

